# A question on how to transfer a property of a stochastic process from a discrete to a continuous index set.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

I am in a situation where I was able to prove that for a stochastic process $X= \{X_t: t \in R_+\} $of relevance to me is such that for every $\delta \in (0, 1) $ I can find a number $K_\delta $ such that
$$P[|X_t|> K_\delta ] < \delta \hskip 10pt \forall t \in [0, n]. $$

The process can be assumed to be a Levy process, or at least a process with independent increments and continuous in probability.

Using an argument based on downcrossings, it is possible to prove that if one considers an index set like $\{0 = r_0 < r_1 < \ldots < r_m\} \in Q\cap [0, n] $ then, 
$$ P[max_{1\le i \le m} |X_{r_i}| > b] < c. $$

K.Ito in his Stochastic Processes concludes that this is sufficient to conclude that
$$ P[\sup_{0 \le t \le n} |X_t| > b] < c, $$
as well.

I am convinced that the fact that $Q \cap [0, n] $ is dense in $[0, n] $ has to play a key role, but I do not seem to be able to put together a rigorous argument.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you.

Maurice

Comment: You'll generally need some kind of pathwise regularity (continuity, cadlag, something to that effect) in order to use good behavior at rational time points to deduce good behavior at irrational time points.

Comment: But once you have that, notice that a continuous function is determined by its values on a dense set...so if it is bounded on a dense set and its domain is compact then it is just bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ satisfies

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \max_{1 \leq i \leq m} |X_{t_i}| > b \right) \leq c \tag{1}$$

for any $t_i \geq 0$, $i=1,\ldots,m$ for some fixed constants $b,c>0$.

If $(t_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of non-negative numbers, then

$$\left\{ \max_{1 \leq i \leq m} |X_{t_i}|>b \right\} \uparrow \left\{ \sup_{i \geq 1} |X_{t_i}|>b \right\}.$$

(This follows directly from the definition of the supremum; if $\sup_{i \geq 1} |X_{t_i}(\omega)|$ is strictly larger than $b$, then we can find some index $m$ such that $\sup_{1 \leq i \leq m} |X_{t_i}(\omega)|>b$.) Using the continuity of the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$, we get

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{i \geq 1} |X_{t_i}|>b \right) = \lim_{m \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{1 \leq i \leq m} |X_{t_i}|>b \right) \stackrel{(1)}{\leq} c. \tag{2}$$

This shows that $(1)$ extends to countable index sets. If we assume additionally that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has càdlàg sample paths (right-continuous with finite left-hand limits), then

$$\sup_{t \in [0,n]} |X_t| = \sup_{t \in [0,n] \cap \mathbb{Q}} |X_t|.$$

Choosing an enumeration $(t_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $[0,n] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, it follows from $(2)$ that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{t \in [0,n]} |X_t|>b \right) = \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |X_{t_i}|>b \right) \leq c.$$

Comment: Thank you Saz for your detailed answer. However, would it be possible to reach the same conclusion without using the assumption of cadlag paths? You see, the reason I am going through this problem is to show that every stochastic process with independent increments and continuous in probability has a cadlag modification. I do not like to have the cadlag requirement built in as part of the definition of a Levy process for then when I work with a process I need to prove that its paths are cadlag or have a modification that is.

Comment: @Maurice Do you want to do it for additive processes or for Lévy processes? For Lévy processes it is somewhat easier, because the stationarity of the increments implies some kind of uniform continuity in probability.

Comment: For Levy processes would be  just fine.. Otherwise I could try proving it for Feller processes which is even more general. I just would like to prove that a Levy process has a cadlag modification. I chose to adopt the line of proof that controls for the number of oscillations instead of using martingales results that force to split the complex martingale in real and imaginary parts. I have all the steps.. I just need to be able to conclude what I am asking. Thank you. If you know how to solve my problem for Levy proc. it would be great..

Comment: @Maurice Sorry, my idea didn't work out... if I have a better one in the next days, I'll tell you. Did you have a look at the book by Revuz & Yor? They prove the result for Feller processes (III.2.7)

Comment: Yes, thank you Saz. I am aware of that proof. Basically, if you use properties of Markov Processes you get the results in more generality. But I was looking for a proof from within Levy processes without going for more generality. I think however, that your original idea, extending the result to countable sets of rationals is going to be enough. Not sure 100%, but I think so.. I just need to write it down properly.   One of the issues with mathematics in general is that we tend to go for beautiful general ideas. In reality, math begins in a very messy way. And only with time it gets general.